# How to convert the data type from object to numeric & then find the mean for each row in pandas ? eg. convert '<17,500, >=15,000' to 16250(mean val)

Tags: python, pandas

```
data['family_income'].value_counts()
>=35,000             2517
<27,500, >=25,000    1227
<30,000, >=27,500     994
<25,000, >=22,500     833
<20,000, >=17,500     683
<12,500, >=10,000     677
<17,500, >=15,000     634
<15,000, >=12,500     629
<22,500, >=20,000     590
<10,000, >= 8,000     563
< 8,000, >= 4,000     402
< 4,000               278
Unknown               128
```

The data column to be shown as a MEAN value instead of values in range

```
data['family_income']
    0        <17,500, >=15,000
    1        <27,500, >=25,000
    2        <30,000, >=27,500
    3        <15,000, >=12,500
    4        <30,000, >=27,500
                   ...        
    10150    <30,000, >=27,500
    10151    <25,000, >=22,500
    10152             >=35,000
    10153    <10,000, >= 8,000
    10154    <27,500, >=25,000
    Name: family_income, Length: 10155, dtype: object
```

Output: as mean imputed value

```
0      16250
1      26250
3      28750
     ...
10152  35000
10153   9000
10154  26500


data['family_income']=data['family_income'].str.replace(',', ' ').str.replace('<',' ')
data[['income1','income2']] = data['family_income'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split(">=")))

data['income1']=pd.to_numeric(data['income1'], errors='coerce')

data['income1']
        0       NaN
        1       NaN
        2       NaN
        3       NaN
        4       NaN
                 ..
        10150   NaN
        10151   NaN
        10152   NaN
        10153   NaN
        10154   NaN
        Name: income1, Length: 10155, dtype: float64
```

In this case, conversion of datatype from object to numeric doesn't seem to work since all the values are returned as NaN. So, how to convert to numeric data type and find mean imputed values?

Comment: Are these values 
`<27,500, >=25,000`  in type `str`?

Comment: yes. Datatype: object

Comment: Some values like `< 4,000 ` and `>=35,000` have only one instance present how do you expect them to be handled?

Comment: these values can be simply returned  as 4000 and 35000

Comment: or somthing like this :      
 data['fam_inc']=np.where(data['family_income']=='Unknown', np.nan,               
      np.where(data['income1'].isnull(), data['income2'],     
                                                                                             np.where(data['income2'].isnull(), data['income1'], 0.5*(data['income1']+data['income2']))))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following snippet:

```
# Importing Dependencies
import pandas as pd
import string

# Replicating Your Data
data = ['<17,500, >=15,000', '<27,500, >=25,000', '< 4,000 ', '>=35,000']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['family_income'])

# Removing punctuation from family_income column
df['family_income'] = df['family_income'].apply(lambda x: x.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)))

# Splitting ranges to two columns A and B
df[['A', 'B']] = df['family_income'].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

# Converting cols A and B to float
df[['A', 'B']] = df[['A', 'B']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

# Creating mean column from A and B
df['mean'] = df[['A', 'B']].mean(axis=1)
```

```
# Input DataFrame
family_income
0   <17,500, >=15,000
1   <27,500, >=25,000
2   < 4,000
3   >=35,000

# Result DataFrame
mean
0   16250.0
1   26250.0
2   4000.0
3   35000.0
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked but had to include errors='coerce' in apply(pd.to_numeric) for my dataframe

Comment: Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (Helps the SO Community) –